# How can one avoid selecting 2 radio buttons with the same value?

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I have a form where I have two groups of radio buttons, names are different but values are shared, so I need to select a radio from the first group, once it's selected the radio from the second group and same value can not be selected, i. e. it becomes disabled...

```
<table>
<tr><th>Origin language</th><th>Target language</th></tr>
<tr><td>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="de">German</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="en">English</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="ca">Catalan</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="es">Spanish</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="fr">French</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="it">Italian</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="pt">Portugues</label>
</td><td>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="de">German</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="en">English</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="ca">Catalan</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="es">Spanish</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="fr">French</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="it">Italian</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="pt">Portugues</label>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you using jquery, or just plain javascript?

Comment: can i use jQuery?

Comment: @Tibin: Yes you can use whatever you think it'll do it, thanks!

Comment: @Matt Spinks I'm using nothing yet, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import jQuery

```
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
 </head>



  <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('input[name=lang_or]').click(function(){

$('input[name=lang_tg]').prop("disabled",false);
$('input[name=lang_tg][value='+this.value).prop("disabled", "disabled");

});

});
</script>
```